# What is the best way to convert any primitive data type to string

Tags: java

I am using the following approach to convert any primitive data type to string

**Example**

```
int i = 5;//
String convertToString = ""+i;// convert any primitive data type to string
```

To convert int data type to string i can use `Integer.toString()` but what is the better way to convert any type of primitive data (not only int) types to string

Comment: Doesn't everything in Java have `.toString()` method?

Comment: @SergeiTulentsev primitives don't

Comment: primitive types are not objects so they don't have toString()

Comment: jeezz.. primitives surely don't have any methods, I was just answering @SergeiTulentsev question, because in the above example `toString()` can't be applied to primitive type `int`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use `String.valueOf()` method.

```
int no = 2;

String strValue = String.valueOf( no );
```

Comment: @HarryJoy Which one? Do you mean string concatenation or toString()

Comment: How about explaining advantage over all other methods?

Comment: I've suggest a method that what I think it is good to convert primitive type value. Integer, Double are classes (wrapper).

Comment: The main adavantage is that there is a String.valueOf method for boolean, char, int, long, float, double and Object, so the same method name can be used to convert anything to a String.

Comment: @JBNizet : I'm not against `valueOf()` method. Actually I'm curious about why this is the best/better to use among all conversion methods?

Comment: It's better, because it creates one new `String` instance instead three. `""+i` is probably translated into `"".concat(String.valueOf(1));`

Comment: Advantage is: it creates string in the reusable [string literal pool](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/what-is-string-literal-pool/3).

Comment: @viktor no, "" is taken from *string pool*, so at maximum 2 new strings are created

Comment: @Santosh if you were referring to `"" + i` snippet, than it's not an advantage. 2 new String instances are created every time, instead of just one as proposed by this answer.

Comment: @jFrenetic, I was referring to this answer only.

Comment: `"" + 1` - there will be created only one object, StringBuilder. This code will be converted to: `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("");
sb.append(1);
String strI = sb.toString();`

Answer (score 5):

I recently ran some benchmarks to compare  `""+myInt` vs `Integer.toString(myInt)`.

And the winner is... `Integer.toString()` !

Because it does not create temporary strings, uses only a adequately-sized char buffer, and some funky algorithms to convert from a digit to its char counterpart.

Here is [my blog entry](http://thecodersbreakfast.net/index.php?post/2011/11/15/Au-coeur-du-JDK-performance-des-conversions) if you read french (or use the sidebar translation widget if you don't)

Answer (score 3):

Consider this example :

```
int i = 42; 
\\ String 
str = Integer.toString(i);
```

In this case you could also do :

```
String str = "" + i;
```

Similarly, one of the easiest way to convert primitive datatypes to String is to use the `toString()` method with the datatype object of the element to be converted.

```
 String str = Double.toString(d); // Convert double to String
 String str = Long.toString(l);  //Convert long to String
 String str = Float.toString(f); //Convert float to String
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define "better".  The most efficient way for the machine is to use

```
String.valueOf(no);
```

or

```
Integer.toString(no);
```

however the most efficient use of your time is to make the code as simple as possible.

```
"" + no;
```

---

This is fairly hot contested decision which reminds me of this quote

> DEVENTER (n) A decision that's very hard to make because so little depends on it, such as which way to walk around a park
>
> -- The Deeper Meaning of Liff by Douglas Adams and John Lloyd.

Comment: Will you please care to explain "*Why `String.valueOf(no);` is the  most efficient way for the machine?*"

Comment: +1 Even though it's "hackalicious", I favour `no + ""` for its brevity and clarity

Comment: I don't find it clear. String.valueOf() and Integer.toString() express the intention clearly. no + "" doesn't, IMHO.

Comment: If you don't the type of `no` the most efficient option is valueOf as this is the closest the actual method used. i.e. this calls the right toString for the type.

Comment: @JBNizet You are right that is a matter of taste. Would you consider `"a" + no` or `"a" + Integer.toString(no)` to be clearer?

Comment: "a" + no. But in this case, the intent is to concatenate. Not to convert.

Comment: Hmmm, since the inputs and outputs are the same, I see the distinction as artificial. Either way you turning a number into a String.

Comment: While I generally agree on the 'make it clear' standpoint, "" + number is such a standard idiom in Java, everybody reads it right.

Comment: `String.valueOf(no);` in case of int simply calls `Integer.toString(no);` - means they are same. However `"" + no;` potentially allocates new empty string that is otherwise not necessary in application at all.

Comment: With PMD becoming a standard tool in Java development, this idiom is less and less frequent, because PMD has a rule to avoid it: http://pmd.sourceforge.net/rules/optimizations.html#AddEmptyString

Comment: In terms of what it is the best use of a developers time, I find it hard to believe this is an improvement.  For me, if performance matters, I wouldn't use String. If performance doesn't matter, its what is the simplest to write and read. If you really think `""+a` is confusing or error prone, don't use it, but I find it hard to believe it is.